# настройки app.config в произвольном файле

Tags: c#, .net

Возможно ли используя механизм System.Configuration часть  настроек хранить в отдельном файле. Мне необходимо хранить часть настроек доступной для редактирования обычными пользователями, а приложение ставится в %ProgramFiles%.
Хотелось бы часть настроек хранить в AppData и часть в ProgramData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите вынести часть настроек из файла app.config в другой - можно использовать атрибут `configSource`.

При помощи этого атрибута можно вынести в отдельный файл (почти) любую секцию:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="connectionstrings.config" />

<!-- Файл connectionstrings.config -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="..." ... />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, такое возможно. Более того, по умолчанию так и происходит.

Порядок чтения настроек такой (более поздние настройки перекрывают более ранние, если только подобное перекрытие не запрещено явно):

- Для настроек приложений - MACHINE/EXE/ROAMING_USER/LOCAL_USER
- Для настроек ASP.NET - MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/virtualPath

Эти файлы можно найти по следующим путям:

- MACHINE - `$(FrameworkPath)\Config\machine.config`
- EXE - `$(ExePath).config`
- ROAMING_USER - `$(UserProfile)\AppData\Roaming\$(CompanyName)\$(AppDomain.FriendlyName ?? ProductName + AppDomain.Evidence)\$(Version)\user.config`
- LOCAL_USER - `$(UserProfile)\AppData\Local\$(CompanyName)\$(AppDomain.FriendlyName ?? ProductName + AppDomain.Evidence)\$(Version)\user.config`

Переменные выше я назвал условно в соответствие с их смыслом, но не следует думать что эти переменные где-то реально существуют. Большинство из них - это временные переменные на стеке в конструкторе приватного класса `System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths`.

Проще всего эти пути получить путем вызова `СonfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.НужныйУровень).FilePath`

Также с помощью метода `OpenExeConfiguration` можно открыть настройки любого уровня с целью редактирования. Но, если вы используете стандартный мастер по созданию настроек студии - то сохранять настройки в профиле пользователя удобнее методом `Save()` сгенерированного студией класса.

Для полноты картины также приведу местонаходжение настроек ASP.NET:

- WEBROOT - находится рядом с machine.config и называется web.config
- APPHOST - `$(windir)system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`
- virtualPath - это один или несколько всем известных файлов web.config вдоль виртуального пути текущего запроса.

Теперь про явный запрет переопределения настроек.

Во-первых, это можно сделать с любым разделом путем установки ему атрибута `lockItem="true"`

Во-вторых, раздел applicationSettings всегда считывается только из конфигурационного файла уровня EXE (он же app.config).

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используте стандартный механизм сеттингов - задаете настройки через файл, лежащий в `Properties\Settings.settings`, то раздельное хранение конфигурации у вас уже есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки, отмеченные, как User, можно менять из кода приложения. Они будут сохранены в `User.config`, в `%APPDATA%` - папке `C:\Users\User\AppData\...`.

По сути - файл Setting - это просто генератор parial класса-наследника от `System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase` - так что его можно легко довести до нужного вам вида, и использовать в качестве хранилища для уже существущей системы настроек (на случай, если вы используете `System.Configuration`, но как-то по-другому).

Comment: ApplicationSettingsBase и System.Configuration - это на самом деле два очень разных механизма. Первый может работать через второй (и по умолчанию так и делает) - но не наоборот.

Comment: @PavelMayorov согласен, и что именно топикастер подразумевал под "механизм System.Configuration" - неизвестно. Вдруг он уже пользуется ApplicationSettings, просто не знает про возможность задать User-level настройки. Просто использовать чистый System.Configuration для хранения пользовательских настроек - несколько тяжеловесное решение, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Вот только User - это значение по умолчанию...

Comment: @PavelMayorov и тем не менее - многие уверены, что значения сеттнгов просто лежат в AppConfig, который лежит в Program Files, и для изменения нужны права админа. Сам видел минимум два старых проекта, которые хранили настройки в Settings, но при этом меняли их через OpenExeConfiguration. И да, требовали права админа на старте :(

Comment: @PavelMayorov я пытаюсь решить проблему топикастера - сохранение настроек пользователя. А не научить его работать с конфигами СonfigurationManager - потому что, *возможно*, ему это и не нужно делать.

Comment: Да, я тоже видел такие проекты. И один из них даже писал... Хотел перенести настройки в User scope из Application Scope - но мне запретили. Сказали, из-за этого пропадут текущие настройки у пользователей :(

Comment: Господа, спасибо за очень развернутые ответы, но видимо я не совсем точно сформулировал вопрос. Идея была в том, чтобы а) задать в app.config при установке дополнительный файл с настройками (по какому пути - это уже выяснится при деплое приложения) так чтобы этот файл могли читать рядовые пользователи б) чтобы механизм считывания и изменения настроек был идентичен как для основного app.config, так и для дополнительного файла. Причина хотелки в том, что с приложением работают на одной и той же машине по несколько пользователей, но изредка им приходится менять глобальные настройки приложения