# Обращение к настройкам из основной программы

Tags: c#, .net, settings

Сделал тестовое приложение состоящее из основной программы и библиотеки. В основной программе завёл файл `.settings`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дерево проектов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если файл настроек создать в библиотеке, то в дальнейшем почему-то не выходит изменить данные. Только после перекомпиляции.
Вот что в выходной папке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В связи с этим решено было конфигурационный файл перенести в основную программу.

```
  public class MyLib
{
    public int myFirstValue = // Tools.Default.FirstValue
}
```

Теперь не понятно, как можно к ней доступ получить? Добавлять ссылку?
Что-то в таком духе. И вообще, как правильно в таком случае поступать?

Comment: Почему не удается изменить данные настроек? компилятор не позволяет или в программе изменяете, а после закрытия программы настройки остаются прежними? если второй случай, то нужно дополнительно в коде после изменения сделать `Tools.Default.Save();`

Comment: Я пытаюсь изменять даже не в рантайме. Закрыл приложение. Поменял в апконфиге - запустил. Но настройки так и не изменяются.

Comment: Меняете в коде или в редакторе настроек?

Comment: В редакторе настроек. Если несколько либ, и у каждой файл настроек, потом в папке мейна куча конфигов. Файлы .settings MyTestLib.dll.config...

Comment: Реализуйте общую библиотеку только с настройками, и подключите ее ко всем объектам которым нужны настройки. Тип данных доступа в настройках должен быть `Пользователь`. Рядом с библиотекой будет лежать `дллнайм.длл.config` вот в нем то и будут все настройки .

Comment: Хороший вариант!

Comment: Если поможет, оформлю как ответ.

Comment: Все-таки думаю необходимо делать конфиг в самом мейне, а от него должны тянуть значения либы. Иначе у меня не выходит. Я меняю в апконфиге, но тщетно. Значения выводит скомпилированные.

Comment: @JDo я попробовал сделать также, как вы. Действительно, если изменять значения параметров через дизайнер или в самом файле, то при компиляции оно все равно будет иметь старое значение, хотя во всех файлах настроек, и в `app.config` оно будет другим. Догадываюсь, что это может быть связано с тем, что файл настроек неправильно соединяется с проектом, который его использует.

Comment: @JDo если вам нужно сделать настройки для приложения, то лучше сделайте так: 1) Зайдите в свойства проекта (Project -> Properties). 2) Выберите вкладку "Параметры" (Settings). 3) Если файла по умолчанию еще нет, то в окне нажмите "Создать". И тут уже работайте, как с `Tool.settings` файлом работали. Здесь должно быть все хорошо.

Comment: @JDo я разобрался. В вашем случае настройки приложения - это настройки Local User, которые хранятся в файле `user.config` в AppData (на системном диске). Почитайте [ответ пользователя Pavel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458492/212981)

Answer (score 1):

Сначала сделал через наследования от класса ConfigurationSection и атрибуты ConfigurationProperty. Получилось работать с общим конфигом из главного приложения. Но подумав, решил не загромождать app.config и пошел по пути наименьшего сопротивления. Сделал библиотеку в которую подключил json файл с настройками (так как у меня нет строк подключения, а просто данные для переменных). Установил NewtonJson. Файл всегда копирую в выходную папку при сборке.

Json:

```
{
   "first": "31",
   "second": "32",
   "third": "33",
   "fourth": "34",
}
```

Класс - модель:

```
public class Settings
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public byte Second { get; set; }
    public byte Third { get; set; }
    public byte Fourth { get; set; }
}
```

Класс для работы с Json:

```
  public class Setup
  {
    string file = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Settings.json");

    public Settings GetSettings()
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(File.ReadAllText(file));
    }

  }
```

И main:

```
   private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Setup s = new Setup();
        Console.WriteLine(s.GetSettings().First);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь при изменении значения в файлике с настройками, изменяется значение в программе.